# html - stretching container height to fit screen

Tags: html, css

I have the HTML below, where I want the container div to stretch to the full height of the window. This works wine, but what happens when you remove two of the blue divs inside the container? The container stretches to the bottom of the blue div inside of it, but not to the bottom of the window. Solution?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xnt014a8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

   <style>
      body, html {
         min-height: 100%;
         padding: 0;
         margin: 0;
      }

      #container {
          height: 100%;
          background: coral;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          width: 63.4%;
          margin-left: 36.6%;
          min-height: 100%;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
     <div style="height: 255px; width: 200px; margin-bottom: 10px; background: blue"></div>
     <div style="height: 255px; width: 200px; margin-bottom: 10px; background: blue"></div>
     <div style="height: 255px; width: 200px; margin-bottom: 10px; background: blue"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to CSS the solution is to use the 'vh' instaed of the '%' in the style.
vh represents the viewport height (1vp = 1% of your viewPort, 2vh = 2% of your viewport....)

so

```
#container {
  height: 100vh;  
  min-height: 100vh;
 ...
}
```

should fix your problem. (works on all major browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple if you want that the container always has the height of the view, just use `100vh` instead of `100%`

```
#container {
          height: 100vh; 
          background: coral;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          width: 63.4%;
          margin-left: 36.6%;
          min-height: 100%;
      }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `body, html` style to:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

OR

```
#container {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below mentioned code:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: coral;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 63.4%;
    margin-left: 36.6%;
}
```

Comment: When 3 blue divs are present, I can still see a small white gap between the bottom of the lowest blue div and the bottom of the window.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the min-height, just simply set height:100%;.

```css
          body, html {
             height: 100%;
             padding: 0;
             margin: 0;
          }

          #container {
              height: 100%;
              background: coral;
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
              width: 63.4%;
              margin-left: 36.6%;
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div style="height: 255px; width: 200px; margin-bottom: 10px; background: blue"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```